# how to change one single column of ActiveRecord AssociationRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

Using Sinatra ActiveRecord and Postgresql. I have a class `Entrees` that has a column `amount` that is `numeric(8,2)`

`entrees = Entrees.all` returns all records.

how can I apply `{ |e|  sprintf('%.2f', e.amount)  }` to entrees in such a manner than only `amount` is altered, but not all the rest of the record? I have tried this:

`ent = entrees.each_entry{ |val| p sprintf('%.2f', val.amount)}`

but with no success. `dig` provokes a no method error.

Comment: `entrees.each { |entree| entree.amount = sprintf('%.2f', e.amount) }` does that not work?

Comment: Yes it did. But I found another solution : `pluck` only the columns I need; put those in a new array of hashes and sprintf on the hash in the array. Saves work in the erb template too.